# h1 blocking other h1 with anchor in it

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

I have two h1 elements, one is a subtitle and is placed behind the first one using z-index. I want to have a click on the first h1. This click needs to go to jQuery because I'm going to use it to stop playback of a video amongst other things. I used to have a click on the first h1 itself, but since its a block element this wasn't ideal as it was stretched over the whole page width. So I replaced that with a dummy anchor .

**My problem is that I can't get the subtitle h1 to stop blocking the title h1. Even when using z-index. Somehow it keeps blocking the first h1**

Ideally the text in both h1's is clickable, but I prefer the title to be clickable.

```html
    <div class="title-box">
      <h1 class="content-title">
        <a href="#" class="content-title-link">FooFooFooFooFoo</a>
      </h1>
      <h1 class="content-subtitle"> Bar </h1>
    </div>
```

Fiddle with my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/nL5pn4w2/4/

Comment: z-index only worked with position, so need to add position relative of that element

Comment: not in a million of years i will click a element covered by another to stop a video playing

Comment: Its the title element for a course page with a video player on it with short educational video's. Clicking the title element should reset the page to show the intro image and stop all playback. Nothing nefarious about it imho.

Comment: I'm not the designer here. I just re-factored 63 static HTML pages into a Laravel based, database backed website  using SASS and common sense to reduce CSS with 60%. That subtitle used to be an `h3:before` 'element' with the text static in a CSS `content` property. **Please get off your high horse.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

z-index only works on positioned elements `position:absolute` , `position:relative` , or `position:fixed`

Another option would be to have the non-link h1 ignore pointer events `pointer-events: none;`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nL5pn4w2/7/)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does `pointer-events` work for touches?

Comment: if `pointer-events` work with touch devices as well it would even be better. But this is already a good solution to my problem.

Comment: use touch-action:auto; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action